# iPad application source code

Tags: ipad

Is there any news application source code project  available for ipad application which implements xml parsing? (Something like New York Times,Newsrack,Malayalamanorama, etc)  I just want to refer that for my news application project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML parsing is fairly straightforward.  Here is a tutorial guiding you through a complete app, from parsing the xml file to displaying the data on the screen:

**[Edumobile: Parsing an XML file](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/)**

(The tutorial says it is for iPhone but there is nothing specific to iPhone there so it is just as relevant for other iOS devices such as iPad or iPod Touch)

For more general guidelines on creating a magazine-like app for the iPad, have a look at this question:

[Programming an iPad compatible magazine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520962/programming-an-ipad-compatible-magazine)